# Creating a Blog with numerous categories

Tags: categories

I'm creating a health conditions site where contributors will make posts. If I want to have multiple people with the "Author Role" be able to post about various categories, do I have to manually create the categories ahead of time...or is there a better way to do this?

Do we increase Author Role permissions to be able to add Categories?

Other solutions welcome. We just need guest authors to be able to add categories while ensuring there is not already a existing appropriate category.

And if I want all categories to show on the sidebar, how would I achieve that prior to there even being a post?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You're asking conflicting questions. If you want your authors to create the categories, then how can a category exist in the sidebar without there being a post?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin to give authors the `manage_categories` capability.

Having said that, if you want to approve all posts before their published, give your users the **contributor** role - this'll also mean you can approve new categories they've added before they appear on the site (by default, only categories that have published posts will appear).

Comment: This would probably be the best route the only other route is to give them editor but then they can edit everyone else's posts. Or just create the categories yourself

Comment: Another option is to go down to contributor and fully monitor them and then assign the categories and publish

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably allow authors to create Categories but keep an eye on it and provide some guidance for the authors on making sure they aren't duplicating and such.

Comment: I guess my question is....by default, authors cannot create categories. How do I allow this?

Comment: Yes, but how do I allow authors to create categories? By default, they can only post and choose a current category.